# Use IntelliJ community to get an AST

Tags: java, parsing, intellij-idea, code-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building a small Java code analysis tool and wonder if I could use the amazing IntelliJ compiler to get an AST for Java projects?

IntelliJ has [open sourced](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/intellij-idea-open-sourced/) the community edition some years ago under the Apache 2 license. Can the project also be used as a library in a Java standalone project (instead of a plugin for a full IDE) to analyze Java projects? The [Git repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) is quite big and I am grateful for any hints or links where to start.

(I have already read about the [Eclipse JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php) but creating my own Mini-ANTLR-Java-parser was much easier than getting the Eclipse JDT to work for me. But it would be amazing if I could use a more sophisticated, always up-to-date version of a Java AST for my project. So my hopes are in the IntelliJ compiler.)

Comment: what do you mean by AST , do you refer to the metamodel of java language in the form of a KDM compliant  ecore ?

Comment: He's referring to the Abstract Syntax Tree, tree-like representation of the structure of java classes that intellij generates when it parses the code. If you write intellij plugins that deal with java (or other languages), this structure and relevant parts of the api will be familiar. OP- do you want to access the AST within intellij, or extrenally and without running intellij?

Comment: Yes I would like to access the Abstract Syntax Tree externally from a Java standalone project, if this is possible?